# RecyclerView item ConstraintLayout messing up while using GridLayoutManager

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-constraintlayout, gridlayoutmanager

I'm using `GridLayoutManager` in my `RecyclerView` with a `spanCount` of 2.
Following is the layout of `RecyclerView` item. It is a `ConstraintLayout` which is wrapped up in a `CardView`:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/cardview_margin"
    android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/white"
    app:cardCornerRadius="4dp">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_title"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:text="Title"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_sub_title"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Subtitle"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/tv_title"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/tv_title"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_title" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_favorite"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:scaleX="1.07"
            android:scaleY="1.07"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_star_blank_grey"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/iv_locked"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/iv_locked"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_locked"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:scaleX="1.0"
            android:scaleY="1.0"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_lock_open_grey"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/iv_favorite"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_sub_title" />
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

The problem arises when `GridLayoutManager` tends to increase the height of a `RecyclerView` item according to the height of the item in second column. Both the `ImageView` icons leave the parent bottom and tend to stick to the `TextView` `tv_sub_title` as in the screenshot below:

[image]

Kindly let me know how to fix this such that both the icons stay at the bottom when the height of the item layout is increased by the `GridLayoutManager`.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, with some hit & trial and taking @Pawel Laskowski answer a bit further, here is what solved the issue:

1. Add `app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1"` attribute to `iv_locked`
2. Change `android:layout_height` of the `ConstraintLayout` from `wrap_content` to `match_parent`.

`ConstraintLayout` is pretty easy to get started with but quite hard to master. Thanks for the help @Pawel Laskowski.

Comment: That's correct, good find. `match_parent` for height is needed for the `ConstraintLayout` to fill the height of the `CardView`. Otherwise there will not be any difference. It's easy to miss.

Answer (score 1):

To keep the `iv_locked` aligned to the bottom between its vertical constraints you need to set the maximum vertical bias by adding the `app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1"` attribute
to it. Since the `iv_favorite` is vertically constrained to the `iv_locked`, it will automatically be in the appropriate position.

Comment: I have already tried using vertical bias but somehow it doesn't  work either.